# JBoss AS 7: Error when use xml-apis.jar

Tags: classnotfoundexception, jboss7.x, antisamy

I'm using anti-samy jar in my project. The class org.w3c.dom.Element is a dependency, and I found under xml-apis jar.

But I'm getting this error when using the app: **org.w3c.dom.Element from [Module "deployment.xxx.ear.antisamy-1.4.4.jar:main" from Service Module Loader]**

I think that I have a classloader hell, but I can't find which module I need.

Info: my app is distributed in EAR, anti-samy and xml-apis are located in root directory into my EAR. The class that I use is located into my EJB module, and in my MANIFEST file I have this classes.

[solved]

**My bad. I've added jars in the root of my EAR. So after I move jars to /lib directory of my EAR, all works fine.**

Answer (score 1):

xml-apis is also present in the JBoss's lib directory, that is JBoss application server use it internally. Check the version of your xml-apis and JBoss xml-apis they should be the same. If JBoss has newever version you should consider to upgrate your application to this version.

Comment: I've removed my jar and added dependency net.sourceforge.nekohtml in my MANIFEST, but the error persists. Nekohtml have org.apache.xerces as dependency that have javax.api as dependency.